# Is it possible to turn off my MHS3528 (ILI9486) TFT backlight?

Tags: screen, power-management, pitft

I've got a TFT screen that uses the [goodtft MHS35-show](https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show/blob/master/MHS35-show) script.

The screen works, and hooray, that's great! Except...

It stays on, all the time, at full brightness. I would love to be able to turn my screen *off* - I realize that I can't control the backlight, due to the hardware. But if I could just... turn off all the GPIO pins or something? And then turn them back on again? That would work great for my needs.

Is there any way I can do this? I tried to use the RPi module in Python but it didn't seem to have any kind of effect.

Comment: It has several pins listed as "power supply"

Comment: I read also this : `vcgencmd set_backlight`
Currently unusable, might be used in the future to control the backlight of LCD displays , maybe try this command ?

Comment: I didn't have that command, and didn't find it in apt search...

Comment: This command is on Raspbian for sure, what is your OS ?

Comment: Raspbian  ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105422/discussion-between-ephemeral-and-wayne-werner).

Comment: Ah let see.  There are a couple to tricks to adjust back lit lighting. (1) The back lit signal is usually a low active signal to resistor pulled up to 3V3/5V0. So you can use a Rpi GPIO pin in Output/PWM mode as a hardware ORed signal. Reference: (a) "LCD Back Lit LED Intensity Hacking Trick":
https://imgur.com/gallery/UngoflB, (2) Locate the backlit SMD resistor, usually 470 to 1k, remove it, and replace it with a faking "variable" value resistor circuit. WARNING: I am just a friendly hobbyist - No guarantee no nothing won't melt down or blow up.

Comment: @tlfong01, I have found this code where one function [void TurnBacklightOff()](https://github.com/juj/fbcp-ili9341/blob/master/ili9486.cpp#L119) is present, but the pin number is require in the compilation step  : `-DGPIO_TFT_BACKLIGHT=number`: Specifies/overrides which GPIO pin to use for the display backlight line. This pin number is specified in BCM pin numbers... Also this parameter `-DBACKLIGHT_CONTROL=ON`. But I don't know how to find this pin number for the MHS3528.

Comment: @tlfong01, also [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi/backlight-control) I can read : `Thanks to the raspberry Pi overlay system, this GPIO is already set up for you in a file called /sys/class/backlight/soc:backlight/brightness` ,  in `On/Off Using STMPE GPIO` part , maybe this is available for the screen ?

Comment: @tlfong01, in the [ILI9486 Datasheet](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/7/78/ILI9486_Datasheet.pdf) section `8.2.39. Write CTRL Display Value (53h) `  page `128` I can see `BL: Backlight Control On/Off `

Comment: @Ephemeral, I agree with what you said about the back lit control option and parameters in the datasheet. The story is a bit long. So let me skim that datasheet and then continue in the chat room. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01, No problem :)

Comment: Was there any solution which could be summarized? i.e. how to turn on/off?